# How to determine the width and height of a GL framebuffer object given only the corresponding id

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I want to determine the size (width, height) of a framebuffer object.

I created a framebuffer object via

```
// create the FBO. 
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
```

How can I get the size of the first color attachment given only the framebuffer object id (`fboId`)?
Is this possible or do I have tor store the size of the color attachment in an external variable to know later the size of the FBO?

Comment: FYI: for better service, use the OpenGL tags for OpenGL questions, even for later versions. Most OpenGL experts look at the OpenGL tag, not the OpenGL-3 one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confused, as you ask for two different things.

Here's the easy question:

> How can I get the size of the first color attachment given only the framebuffer object id (fboId)?

That's simple: get the texture/renderbuffer attached to that attachment, get what mipmap level and array layer is attached, then query the texture/renderbuffer for how big it is.

The first two steps are done [with `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter) (note the key word "Attachment") for `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. You query the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE` to get whether it's a renderbuffer or a texture. You can get the renderbuffer/texture name with `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_NAME`.

If the object is a renderbuffer, you can then bind the renderbuffer and use [`glGetRenderbufferParameter`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetRenderbufferParameter) to fetch the renderbuffer's `GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH` and `GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT`.

If the object is a texture, you'll need to do more work. You need to query the attachment parameter `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_TEXTURE_LEVEL` to get the mipmap level.

Of course, now you need to know how to bind it. If you're using OpenGL versions before 4.4 or without certain extensions, then this is complicated. See, you need to know which [texture target type](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Theory) to use. Silly and annoying as this may seem, the only way to determine the target from just the texture object name is to... try everything. Go through each target and check `glGetError`. The one for which `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` *isn't* returned is the right one.

If you have GL 4.4 or [ARB_multi_bind](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_bind.txt) available, you can just [use `glBindTextures`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Multibind_and_textures) (note the "s"), which does not require that you specify the target. And if you have 4.5 or [ARB_direct_state_access](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/direct_state_access.txt), you don't need to bind the texture at all. The DSA-style functions don't need the texture target, and it also provides `glBindTextureUnit`, which binds a texture to its natural internal target.

Once you have the texture bound and it's mipmap level, you [use `glGetTexLevelParameter`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetTexLevelParameter) to query the `GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH` and `GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT` for that level.

Now, that's the *easy* problem. The hard problem is what your title asks:

> I want to determine the size (width, height) of a framebuffer object.

The size of the renderable area of an FBO is *not the same* as the size of `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. The renderable area of an FBO is the intersection of all of the sizes of all of the images attached to the FBO.

Unless you have special knowledge of this FBO, you can't assume that the FBO contains only one image or that all of the images have the same size (and if you have special knowledge of the FBO, then quite frankly you should *also* have special knowledge of how big it is). So you'll need to repeat the above procedure for *every* attachment (if the type is `GL_NONE`, then nothing is attached). Then take the intersection of the returned values (ie: the smallest width and height).

In general, you shouldn't have to ask an FBO that you created how big it is. Just as you don't have to ask textures how big they are. You made them; by definition, you know how big they are. You put them in the FBO, so again you know how big it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and btw, every time I ask an OpenGL question I find  one of your answers: I don't know how much time you spend on SO, but you sure deserve every single rep point you have :) )

Comment: How do I know which target to bind the framebuffer's attached texture to? (E.g. GL_TEXTURE_2D? GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP? etc.)
The OBJECT_TYPE returns just "GL_TEXTURE" and I don't see any way to query the actual texture target.

Comment: @namey: Just bind it as every possible texture target; the one that *doesn't* result in an error is the right one. You may think I'm being sarcastic, but I am in fact totally serious. This is the *only way* to know what a texture's type is if all you have is the texture object. Alternatively, use ARB_direct_state_access and you won't have to care.